# Is there any custom mysql input event adapter for wso2 cep

Tags: wso2-cep

I wanted to have the event recevier/stream from DB instead of jms,email,http.
In wso2 cep mysql/db is available as only output adapter not as intput adapter.
So is there any custom mysql input adapter available.
Please let me know if there is any alternative solution for db adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that WSO2 CEP does not have an Input Event Adapter to recieve events from a database (You can find the [list of available input event adapters in the product documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Configuring+Event+Receivers)).

To my understanding, this is mainly because WSO2 CEP is designed for **realtime** stream processing.

I guess, here the database is not the original source which generates the events?
If so, there should be another event publisher which writes to the database. If you have the control over this publisher, would n't it be possible to get that publisher to send events to the WSO2CEP server directly, rather than writing to the database and then reading from it? 
In my opinion, that will be a better solution compared to reading from the database.

Comment: Hi, Dilini Thanks for the reply. In my case DB will be my source of events, we are using CDC in SQL server , so our source of events will be CDC temp table. I tried with the creating custom input even adapter ( sample ) but it throughed alot of exceptions because the example was for CEP version 3.1.0 , i didnt find the example for 4.1.0 CEP version.If possible let me know is there any custom input event adapter for CEP 4.1.0 version

Comment: Hi Sanath, please find the document on Building Custom Event Receiver for CEP 4.1.0 version: https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Building+Custom+Event+Receivers

Comment: Thanks Dilini, i will go through the link.